# Symfony2 - Very slow initialization time after login

Tags: symfony

I have an application built with Symfony2, currently with 32 entities.
The current version of Symfony is v.2.3.13.

I´m using a VM in VirtualBox provisioned by Vagrant in development, with Ubuntu Server 14.04.
I´m running this application in production in an Ubuntu 13.10 Server. It´s a VM with 8 cores and 4GB RAM.
I have ApcClassLoader enabled in app.php.
I have used SecurityBundle for authentication, and all pages need the user authenticated to be accessed.

In both environment, when the user enter the username and password, and click on "Enter" button, the login action is quick. But in the next click (and only in this click), the system take a long time to respond. 
The average time is about 60 seconds. But sometimes it takes until 180 seconds.
After this the system works normally. 
Look the Timeline in Profiler after a login in development env:

[image]

This didn´t happen when the system was a little smaller.
I already tried dozens of things to fix it.
I don´t know more what to do.

Anyone have some idea about what could be this?

### Edit

The rest of requests after initialization takes less than 1 second. Look the profiler timeline graph:
[image]

Comment: The timeline should also show what request(s) are bottlenecking. [For example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xJayg.png)

Comment: It doesn´t. The rest of requests in the graph takes less than 1 second.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to find the part where it takes so long?

Comment: This may or may not be related to Symfony, VMs can sometimes be slow to move things back to active memory. Can you tell which component is taking all that time? My guess is this is related to an SQL db being loaded into active memory after being inactive for a time. If you can tell where the bottleneck is, though, that might help diagnose it.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t know what part or what component is taking the time. I suspect this don´t related to Symfony. I have almost twenty years of experience with LAMP servers, and tried and look everything I know, but have no success. I am going to be crazy with this. I appreciate your attempts to help anyway!

Comment: I have a good amount of experience with Symfony, but without knowing which part is causing the delay, it's not easy to figure out. Symfony is a complex system. That said, you might want to look at caching, authentication, or the DB. 90% chance the issue is within one of those three systems if it only happens during the first page request.

Comment: Perhaps xhprof can be useful in your situation ? this module helps me a lot when i have perf issues !